# Making my submenu visible while the parent is focused using tab

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been stuck with a problem with my custom WordPress theme for a long time.

As you might know, you need to be able to navigate the menu using keyboard only. This is possible in my case.

However, I can't see the submenu while I'm moving through it using tab. I know it moves through the menu because when I've hit tab for every submenuitem there is, the visual cue for being focused moves to next parent menu item.

Also if I remove some of the styling so that I can see all menu items at all times (which isn't very practical), it works just fine.

I hide the submenu by default using left: -999em;. then when I hove over its parent menu item, I bring the submenu to view by using left:0;.

This works perfectly using :hover, but not with :focus. Can anyone tell me why? Here is some of my css.

```
header .navigation li{
    position: relative;
}

header .navigation li .sub-menu {
    position: absolute !important;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 100%;
    left: -999em;
    background-color: lightgray;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: .5rem;
}

header .navigation li .sub-menu a{
    display: block;
    padding: .25rem;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none; 
}

header .navigation li .sub-menu a:hover,
header .navigation li .sub-menu a:focus
{   
    color: white; /* BOTH WORK*/
}

header .navigation > .menu-item-has-children:hover > .sub-menu,
header .navigation > .menu-item-has-children:focus > .sub-menu
{
    left: 0; /* ONLY THE :HOVER WOKRS */
}
```

Hope I explained this well enough (my first post here lol).

Testing the minimal working example.

```css
header .navigation {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  width: 900px;
  word-break: keep-all;
}

header .navigation li a {
  padding: .25rem 1rem;
  color: #000;
  width: 100%;
}

header .navigation li:first-child a {
  padding-left: 0;
}

header .navigation li {
  position: relative;
}

header .navigation li .sub-menu {
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 100%;
  left: -999em;
  background-color: lightgray;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: .5rem;
}

header .navigation li .sub-menu:focus {
  left: 0;
}

header .navigation li .sub-menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: .25rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header .navigation li .sub-menu a:hover,
header .navigation li .sub-menu a:focus {
  color: white;
  /*BOTH WORK*/
}

header .navigation>.menu-item-has-children:hover>.sub-menu,
header .navigation>.menu-item-has-children:focus>.sub-menu {
  left: 0;
  /* ONLY THE :HOVER WOKRS */
}
```

```html
<header class="sticky-top">

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <h1>test</h1>

    <div class="menu-all-pages-container">
      <ul id="menu-all-pages" class="navigation">
        <li id="menu-item-1636" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1636"><a href="http://wpthemetestdata.wordpress.com/">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1637" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1637"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=703">Blog</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1638" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1638"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=701">Front Page</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1639" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1639"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=2">About The Tests</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu" tabindex="0">
            <li id="menu-item-1760" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1760"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=1133">Page Image Alignment</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1761" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1761"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=1134">Page Markup And Formatting</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1640" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1640"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=501">Clearing Floats</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1641" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1641"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=155">Page with comments</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1642" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1642"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=156">Page with comments disabled</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-1643" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1643"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=174">Level 1</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-1644" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1644"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=173">Level 2</a>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-1645" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1645"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=172">Level 3</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-1762" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1762"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=746">Level 3a</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-1763" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1763"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=748">Level 3b</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-1764" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1764"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=742">Level 2a</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1765" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1765"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=744">Level 2b</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-1646" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1646"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=146">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1766" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1766"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=733">Page A</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1767" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1767"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=735">Page B</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: If the issue is primarily the CSS, you add a minimal working example? The code button in the question editor (the hint is something like "JavaScript/HTML/CSS") allows you to directly embed a website.

Comment: I've now added the minimal working example (hope I did it right). The html is just a copy of my local host wordpress site so I'd focus on the css. As you can see, menu items 'about the tests' and 'level 1' have submenu items. While hovering, it works fine. With tab 'about the tests' shows the submenu but it disappears as soon as it's not focused anymore. I guess the question is: is there a way to show .submenu background while focusing its a elements? @Elias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `tabindex='0'` property to the `.sub-menu` element if you haven't to make it focusable. Not all elements are focusable. `:focus` on `<a>` tag works because it is focusable as long as it has either `href` or `tabindex` attribute. Refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) for more on tabindex.

**Edit:** I have checked the code and it looks like you want the `.sub-menu` to stay visible when the links inside it are focused as well. So add this style for that and it should work. You want the left position of the `.sub-menu` to be 0 as long as the links inside it are focused.

```css
header .navigation > .menu-item-has-children > .sub-menu:focus-within {
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: If I'm correct, you can't add tabindex with css, right? This is a menu created by WordPress using wp_nav_menu (.sub-menu class is created automatically with this or not sure if it's jquery) and I'm not sure how to add tabindex to it.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Currently there seems no way to add with css. However, you can always use javascript and do something like `document.querySelector(".sub-menu").tabIndex = 0;`

Comment: I added that to my scripts.js. Now it seems that nothing changed except that the focus indicator can also be seen along the borders of the whole submenu. It is still not acting the same way as the :hover. I noticed that now if I add this to my css : "header .navigation li .sub-menu:focus { left: 0; }", it makes the submenu visible when I focus the parent. But when I tab to enter the submenu, it disappears again.

Comment: It is quite hard to simply help here since you haven't posted the minimal code. Would it possible to create a sandbox of what you are trying to achieve? It would make me easier to help.

Comment: I've now added the minimal working example (hope I did it right). The html is just a copy of my local host wordpress site so I'd focus on the css. As you can see, menu items 'about the tests' and 'level 1' have submenu items. While hovering, it works fine. With tab 'about the tests' shows the submenu but it disappears as soon as it's not focused anymore. I guess the question is: is there a way to show .submenu background while focusing its a elements?

Comment: I have edited my answer and you can take a look at it.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot mate. Didn't even know there was such a thing as :focus-within

Comment: ... you just did what I did in my answer :(

Comment: I know, yours was just as good <3 This was just a bit more simple since it's just a simple line of css that can be immediately added to my code and it instatly works.

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty to re-write the code a bit since there was a lot of noise. If you can, next time only post the code that is absolutely necessary to demonstrate the problem :).

Since the code is now different from yours, you might need to make some changes. If you are unable to apply them, please leave a comment, and I'll see if I can adapt it more closely to what you posted.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
}

.nav li {
  flex: 1;
}

.about-the-tests {
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}


/* Opens the menu when the "About the Tests" link is focused */

.about-the-tests a:focus+.sub-menu,

/* Keeps the menu open when a link is focused inside it */

.about-the-tests:focus-within .sub-menu {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="https://example.com">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://example.com">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://example.com">Front Page</a></li>
    <li class="about-the-tests">
      <a href="https://example.com">About the Tests</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="https://example.com/page_image_alignment">Page Image Alignment</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://example.com/page_markup_and_formatting">Page Markup And Formatting</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://example.com/clearing_floats">Clearing Floats</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://example.com/page_with_comments">Page with comments</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://example.com/page_with_comments_disabled">Page with comments disabled</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://example.com">Level 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

The main thing I added was the `focus-within` pseudo class.

I also changed how the display is hidden. Now it's hidden using the `visibility` property. You can also try it with the `display` property, but I don't know how well screen readers deal with that. Anyway, I think both of those approaches are cleaner than moving the elements off the screen.

*Also: Try avoiding `!important`. It's almost always a mistake in your CSS, as later CSS rules may always overwrite previous ones.*

Comment: I know the html was a bit messy. This is from my custom wp theme and there is no actual html for the menu in my code, it's all wordpress generated. The guys from wordpress told me to not use display and I know another theme that uses this method so i figured I'd give it a try. I'll give these a try and see how it goes!